# Hashing function Sha256 untraceable?

Tags: algorithm, hash, sha256

Why cant you reverse a hashed file, hashed with Sha256?
Shouldnt you be able to reverse every
mathematically function back?
Like you can reverse a 5*9 by dividing 45 by 9

Comment: Reverse 109 modulo 10.  You get 9.  But there's no way to tell if you started with 109 or 10000000009....

Comment: And Google "pigeonhole principle".  It's highly applicable to hashes.

Answer (score 2):

> Like you can reverse a 5*9 by dividing 45 by 9

Given that *x*·9 = 45, you can recover *x*; but given that *x*·*y* = 45, you can't recover (*x*, *y*), because there are many possibilities: maybe (*x*, *y*) = (5, 9), or maybe (*x*, *y*) = (9, 5), or maybe (*x*, *y*) = (3, 15), or . . .

Which is to say: SHA-256 doesn't have to guarantee that two distinct inputs will give two distinct outputs (and in fact, it can't guarantee that, because there are infinitely many possible inputs and only 2<sup>256</sup> possible outputs), so it doesn't have to be, and isn't, a series of mathematically reversible functions like "multiply by 9".

Answer (score 0):

SHA256 hash can map more different inputs to the same output meaning many files can have the same hash. This hash has constant small amount of bits that simply can not hold the "infinite" combinations of data it can process. So you can not reverse ... which is the main purpose of a hash from cryptography point of view.

And no you can not inverse all math functions ... (at least we still do not know how)

Even your example can not be inversed in general without adding some other information (like you used one of the operands of original input) ...